# Changeman on host mainframe - What does each step mean?

Tags: mainframe, change-management

I'm currently trying to promote a package in Changeman on mainframe. Currently it seems like there it's a series of incantations that I have to follow. Unfortunately, I can't remember magic incantations. I need to understand what's going on before I can follow. So, what's involved in Changeman, and what do the following mean: Stage, Checkout, Audit, and what do they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChangeMan is strict but fair! :-)

Seriously though. ChangeMan does take some getting use to but after that it does make ones development-process more uniform and streamlined.

Stage:
Tells at witch development-stage the package is.
The most important are:
DEV for "Under development"
FRZ for "Frozen" (Locked for alterations and FTP/copy scripts are generated)
AUD for "Audited" (see below)
BAS for "Baseline" (Current version in production)

Audit:
Means to run a check on the changes you made (contained in the package) to see if there is harmful and/or problematic issues in regards to production-code. Like changes to a interface. Then all programs using the interface has to be changed as well.

Checkout:
As in other version/source control system, is means to check out the code so that none else can.

Regards
           Sigersted